# Ideal framework for map with live data provided by csv file

Tags: javascript, api, next.js, leaflet, folium

I've been working on a map for a personal project based on my day job. Folium has worked for me as a temporary solution but would like something more suited for live data on desktop and mobile browsers.

I would like suggestions for plotting static lat/lng location data on a map where the status of the plot and data associated with it is changing by the minute at times. The dataset contains 15k rows and 12 columns.

This data is currently in csv format but could be changed if needed. Geojson data is used to produce polygon overlays, the ability to filter the plotted data by status, and data from API's will be needed eventually as well. A search bar of the data plotted and address search would be very useful here.

What are my options for this type of application? From my Google searches it looks like NextJS with Leaflet might be the route i need to take.

I've not worked with it before but am looking to make this application more feature rich for myself and others.

I realize this will be a challenge but i've enjoyed working to put all the pieces together for the Folium version.

Any suggestions?

I used Folium so far.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, I haven't found anything that doesn't involve a lot of custom code. There are a lot of moving pieces from data formats enforcement to user level security and scalability.

My personal solution was a JavaScript frontend that builds an API contract. Basically I read the header row and turn that into a JSON object in the from of an OpenAPI contract. I build the schema using the first data row for examples.

```
dogsname, dogscolor, dogsbreed
"Lassie", "Golden", "Collie"
"Brian", "White", "Mutt"
```

which becomes

```
"dogs": {
    "title": "The request and base object for dogs",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "dogsname": {
        "type": "string",
        "example": "Lassie",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255,
        "format": "text"
      },
      "color": {
        "type": "string",
        "example": "Golden",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255,
        "format": "text"
      },
      "dogsbreed": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "text",
        "example": "Collie",
        "minLength": 0,
        "maxLength": 255
      }
```

Then I build out the paths in the OpenAPI contract using the base object to describe the collection and object with GET, POST, PUT and DELETE to create a portable contract that *describes* the API.

But this is where it gets fractured.  I ended up building my own API gateway and backend that runs enforcement based on that OpenAPI contract.  There are some other tools that can use the contract to inform the gateway but most of them are enterprise solutions (Apigee for example has [a script](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/tutorials/create-api-proxy-openapi-spec) but Apigee isn't priced for small projects).

Because there are so many moving pieces I can't appropriately share my code here, but feel free to  all very much in beta, but you can see the overview here: [UXAPI: Design an API](https://uxapi.io/design-overview.html)